# Using the Facebook Graph API, can you detect if a Page Post is boosted / sponsored / suggested?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an app that enhances Facebook Insight analytics with competitor information. When a Page post is 'boosted' the post is tagged as 'sponsored' and labelled as a suggested post on FB web and mobile. Can I get this from the Graph API for a particular post?

Comment: If you have admin access to the page you want to check, just see if your post_paid_reach is bigger than 0. If you don't I would suggest to gather public data and then mage an interactions average - the posts with a spike were quite likely boosted - I have made this in the past, let me know if you need a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very well-documented what is available for Posts:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post#fields

From what is stated there, I highly doubt that you can retrieve the kind of info you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, yes you are correct this info is not available. If a post is boosted it is labeled with 'suggested' and 'sponsored' in a viewer's newfeed. But the post itself is not flagged in anyway. If you query it in the Graph API or even go direct (www.facebook.com/{post-id}) then there is no evidence that it is a boosted post.